# Difficulty importing from sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

When I try to import from sklearn

```
from sklearn import neighbours, datasets
```

I get the following:

---

> ImportError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in 
>       ----> 1 from sklearn import neighbours, datasets
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'neighbours' from 'sklearn' 
>       (C:\Users\35386\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py)

I have 0.20.1 (from Anaconda3)

Comment: The module is named neighbors :) American spelling

Answer (score 1):

use neighbors instead of neighbours

```
from sklearn import neighbors, datasets
```